# How can i configure my supervisor to handle the queues inside the laravel project's Jobs table?

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jobs, supervisord

I have a running supervisor(for queue management) in my elastic beanstalk ec2 server.Also there are queues inside the jobs table.How can i configure my supervisor to handle the queues inside the jobs table.
This is my supervisor.d/laravel.conf configuration:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/storage/laravel-queue.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Is there any additional configuration that i need to add ??

Comment: Add another section in your configuration that handles the db queue. (Copy paste what is in your current supervisor configuration and rename the top big e.g. `[program:laravel-worker-db-queue]` or similar and then change the command to use db instead of sqs)